# Dynamic suggestions for text ctrl in wxPython?

Tags: dynamic, wxpython, textctrl

Is there any way to mimic the dynamic suggestions behavior as per the search field on Google? As in, I type something in a text ctrl, and a list of suggestions pops up below for the user to chose from? If wxPython doesn't have such a feature, perhaps some other Python gui has it?

EDIT: For use on a Mac. That excludes [this](http://wiki.wxpython.org/TextCtrlAutoComplete) example, although it seems to be exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure it theres a way to automatically do this but I think it could be easily achieved by binding to  `EVT_TEXT`.

[This](http://wiki.wxpython.org/TextCtrlAutoComplete) is a recipe from the wxpython wiki for a TextCtrlAutoComplete control

Comment: Yea I found that wiki entry too. The problem is that I'm intending to use it on a Mac, which doesn't support the popupWindow. I better edit the question.

Comment: Ok sorry I couldnt help more, if I think of something Ill post back.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [AutocompleteTextCtrl](http://bitbucket.org/raz/wxautocompletectrl/wiki/Home)?

You could quickly download and test it as it comes with a nice test module to run straight away.

Comment: will take a look at it, but I'd assume it's based on wx.PopupWindow that isn't supported on mac...

Comment: I don't think it is based on wx.PopupWindow at all. Instead it uses a HtmlListBox inside a wx.Frame which is just shows and hides.